# get the indexes before and after the substring

Tags: python, string, substring

substring_list = ['Apples', 'bananas', 'pear']
mystr = "Apples are good for your health morethan bananas"
for word in substring_list:
  if word in mystr:
  # how to get before and after the indexes of a substring

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Comment: `index` gets you the starting index.  `len` tells you how long the search target is.  Where are you stuck in computing the indices you want?

Comment: are good for your health morethan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a `list comprehension` to easily create tuples of values found in your list and find the start (inclusive) and end of them (not inclusive). Additionally, by shifting everything to `lower()`, you can make sure that you're capturing both upper and lower case instances.

```
indices = [(mystr.lower().find(x.lower()), mystr.lower().find(x.lower()) + len(x)) for x in substring_list if mystr.lower().find(x.lower()) != -1]
indices    
[(0, 6), (41, 48)]
```

**EDIT**

```
for i, j in list(reversed(indices)):
     mystr = mystr.replace(mystr[i:j],'')
mystr
' are good for your health morethan '
```

Comment: @srikar see revision

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
list_mystr = list(mystr)

for idx, word in enumerate(substring_list):
    if word in list_mystr:
        before_idx = idx - 1
        after_idx = idx + 1
```